# Rules with shared shell section

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to have 2 rules that share the same shell section? (without duplicating the shell contents)
Otherwise, how to write a single rule that would have different input and ouput contents depending on the value of a parameter?

Comment: You can store your shell section as a python string and use that string as the shell section of two different rules.

Comment: Thanks @RussHyde, that works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Write a [python function to choose input files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#functions-as-input-files) as needed based on wildcards. You could also use lambda function as in this example:

```
rule xxx: 
    input:
        lambda wildcards: "data/A.txt",
                if wildcards.sample == 'voted' \
                else \
                    "data/B.txt",
    output:
        "data/{sample}/done.txt"
    shell:
        "do something"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it does not work for the output section.